# Preview hidden equation - alignment is broken

Tags: bug

I was [answering a homework question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/114921/26969), and wanted to include some "hidden answers" to give the OP a chance to work it out bit by bit. Some of the layout etc. of the equations is different in preview - it was OK in the actual answer.  For example, in preview:

[image]

Becomes

[image]

in the actual answer. Clearly the preview is left aligned, but the equations become centered in the answer.

There were other issues in preview - some text followed by a block of multi-line equations 
`This is a problem: $$..\\..\\..$$` ended up on the same line during preview:

[image]

Preview is such an important feature - especially when you do things like equations. It would be nice if it would work together with the "hidden answer" feature.

Comment: I think a more important question is "Why would someone want to hide an equation?"

Comment: @KyleKanos The idea is (was) to be able to write a solution that gives the OP a chance to "try some things for himself" after just being given a few hints - whilst not having to return later to fill in the details and making it an answer that's useful "later". That, at least, is my thinking behind "wanting to hide an equation". That said, I have since seen more posts about the homework policy on this site - and thank you (and DavidZ) for pointing me to those. In general though, this appears to me to be a bug.